# Create 1 list in Excel from 2 other lists

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two lists in Excel, one with the columns `Code`, `Company`, `Email` and `Invoice` (sheet 1) and another list with the columns `Code`, `Company` and `Invoice` (sheet 2).
Now, how can I create a new list that only contains rows where the value in the column `Code` in sheet 1 is identical to the value in the column `Invoice` in sheet 2?

EDIT: OK, so I used MATCH in Sheet1 as suggested like this:
=MATCH(A3,Sheet2!D:D,0)
However this only returns the row number when there is a match. But I need to return a specific cell value in Sheet2 for every row where there is a match. How can I do that?

Comment: Just make a calculation column in which you use Match to find if there is a match, and let it display a 1 if true. Just filter on the 1's then.

Comment: you can try this https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/

Comment: Thanks! See my edit. I have tried using an IF statement to return a specific cell value when there is a match, but I can't figure out quite how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I get exactly but I suppose you want to import from sheet2 to sheet1 some columns where there's match `sheet1/code = sheet2/invoice`. You can try this formula in `Sheet1 E3` then copy/paste it in all cells that you want to import:

```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!E:E, MATCH($A3,Sheet2!$D:$D,0)), "")
```